# Handle errors in GEE Code editor

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I am trying to export a CSV file containing numeric data for many locations but Sentinel-1 grd does not have VV and VH data at certain locations and it is throwing errors. How to handle them and proceed with exporting what ever information is available.

My code looks like this

```
function getData(coords){
  // Get the coordinates of the point of interest
  var location = ee.Geometry.Point(coords);

  // Define the start and end dates for the image collection
  var startDate = '2020-01-01';
  var endDate = '2020-01-10';

  try{
  // Load the Sentinel-1 image collection for VV and VH polarizations
  var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filterBounds(location)
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .select(['VV', 'VH']);

  // Calculate the mean backscatter for the 1km x 1km area around the point of interest
  var meanSentinel1 = sentinel1.mean()
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: location.buffer(500), // use 500m buffer around the point to get a 1km x 1km area
      scale: 10, // use 10m scale for Sentinel-1 data
      maxPixels: 1e9
    });
    
  var smap = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/SMAP/SPL4SMGP/007")
           .filterBounds(location)
           .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
           .select(['sm_surface', 'sm_surface_wetness']);
  // print(meanSentinel1);
  var sm_surface = smap.select('sm_surface')
                     .filterBounds(location)
                     .first()
                     .reduceRegion({
                       reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
                       geometry: location,
                       scale: 9000
                     })
                     .get('sm_surface',null);
  var sm_surface_wetness = smap.select('sm_surface_wetness')
                     .filterBounds(location)
                     .first()
                     .reduceRegion({
                       reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
                       geometry: location,
                       scale: 9000
                     })
                     .get('sm_surface_wetness',null);

  //print(sm_surface);
  // Create a feature to represent the location and mean backscatter values
  var feature = ee.Feature(null);
  feature = feature.set('latitude', coords[1]);
  feature = feature.set('longitude', coords[0]);
  feature = feature.set('VV_mean',meanSentinel1.get('VV',null));
  feature = feature.set('VH_mean',meanSentinel1.get('VH',null));

  // Calculate the soil roughness
  //var soilRoughness = (meanSentinel1.get('VV') - meanSentinel1.get('VH')) / (meanSentinel1.get('VV') + meanSentinel1.get('VH'));
  // print(smap.select('sm_surface').first());
  // Add the soil roughness to the feature
  //feature=feature.set('soil_roughness', soilRoughness);
  feature=feature.set('sm_surface_wetness',sm_surface_wetness);
  feature=feature.set('sm_surface',sm_surface);
  print(feature);
  return feature;
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    feature=feature.set('sm_surface_wetness',null);
  feature=feature.set('sm_surface',null);
  feature = feature.set('latitude', coords[1]);
  feature = feature.set('longitude', coords[0]);
  feature = feature.set('VV_mean',null);
  feature = feature.set('VH_mean',null);
  }
}

  var coordinates=[[19.533, -155.933], [37.633, -113.65], [-119.9, 39.16], [41.75, -117.53], [-109.233, 38.317], [146.41398, -34.84697], [-79.733, 34.3], [-112.15, 35.14], [48.15473, 15.14844], [-107.0904, 39.37939]];
  // Create a list of features
  var features = [];

  // Iterate through the coordinates
  for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    // Create a feature
    var feature = getData([coordinates[i][1],coordinates[i][0]]);

    // Add the feature to the list
    features.push(feature);
  }

  // Export the features as a CSV file to your Google Drive
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection(features),
    description: 'sentinel1_mean_backscatter_soil_roughness',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    selectors: ['latitude', 'longitude', 'VV_mean', 'VH_mean','sm_surface_wetness','sm_surface']
  });
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? What changes should I make to the code?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: He said: "Sentinel-1 grd does not have VV and VH data at certain locations".

Answer (score 1):

Issues in your code are related to the inversion of the order of coordinates (longitude, latitude) for some points. I fixed them placing the longitude, latitude values in its corresponding order and modifying **getData** function for creating features in the adequate way as follows:

```
var feature = getData([coordinates[i][0],coordinates[i][1]]);
```

Complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7e0879e754c61a1dbad63cd0941a2ab4) looks as follows:

```
function getData(coords){
  // Get the coordinates of the point of interest
  var location = ee.Geometry.Point(coords);

  // Define the start and end dates for the image collection
  var startDate = '2020-01-01';
  var endDate = '2020-01-10';

  try{
  // Load the Sentinel-1 image collection for VV and VH polarizations
  var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filterBounds(location)
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .select(['VV', 'VH']);

  // Calculate the mean backscatter for the 1km x 1km area around the point of interest
  var meanSentinel1 = sentinel1.mean()
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: location.buffer(500), // use 500m buffer around the point to get a 1km x 1km area
      scale: 10, // use 10m scale for Sentinel-1 data
      maxPixels: 1e9
    });
    
  var smap = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/SMAP/SPL4SMGP/007")
           .filterBounds(location)
           .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
           .select(['sm_surface', 'sm_surface_wetness']);
  // print(meanSentinel1);
  var sm_surface = smap.select('sm_surface')
                     .filterBounds(location)
                     .first()
                     .reduceRegion({
                       reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
                       geometry: location,
                       scale: 9000
                     })
                     .get('sm_surface',null);
  var sm_surface_wetness = smap.select('sm_surface_wetness')
                     .filterBounds(location)
                     .first()
                     .reduceRegion({
                       reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
                       geometry: location,
                       scale: 9000
                     })
                     .get('sm_surface_wetness',null);

  //print(sm_surface);
  // Create a feature to represent the location and mean backscatter values
  var feature = ee.Feature(null);
  feature = feature.set('latitude', coords[1]);
  feature = feature.set('longitude', coords[0]);
  feature = feature.set('VV_mean',meanSentinel1.get('VV',null));
  feature = feature.set('VH_mean',meanSentinel1.get('VH',null));

  // Calculate the soil roughness
  //var soilRoughness = (meanSentinel1.get('VV') - meanSentinel1.get('VH')) / (meanSentinel1.get('VV') + meanSentinel1.get('VH'));
  // print(smap.select('sm_surface').first());
  // Add the soil roughness to the feature
  //feature=feature.set('soil_roughness', soilRoughness);
  feature=feature.set('sm_surface_wetness',sm_surface_wetness);
  feature=feature.set('sm_surface',sm_surface);
  print(feature);
  return feature;
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    feature=feature.set('sm_surface_wetness',null);
  feature=feature.set('sm_surface',null);
  feature = feature.set('latitude', coords[1]);
  feature = feature.set('longitude', coords[0]);
  feature = feature.set('VV_mean',null);
  feature = feature.set('VH_mean',null);
  }
}

var coordinates=[[-155.933, 19.533], 
                 [-113.65, 37.633], 
                 [-119.9, 39.16],
                 [-117.53, 41.75],
                 [-109.233, 38.317], 
                 [146.41398, -34.84697],
                 [-79.733, 34.3],
                 [-112.15, 35.14],
                 [15.14844, 48.15473], 
                 [-107.0904, 39.37939]];

  // Create a list of features
  var features = [];

  // Iterate through the coordinates
  for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    // Create a feature
    var feature = getData([coordinates[i][0],coordinates[i][1]]);

    // Add the feature to the list
    features.push(feature);
  }

  // Export the features as a CSV file to your Google Drive
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection(features),
    description: 'sentinel1_mean_backscatter_soil_roughness',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    selectors: ['latitude', 'longitude', 'VV_mean', 'VH_mean','sm_surface_wetness','sm_surface']
  });
```

After running it in GEE code editor, I could export **sentinel1_mean_backscatter_soil_roughness.csv** file without any error as it can be observed in following picture:

[image]